# Postpone static variable construction in C++

Tags: c++

On our project we have external RAM that is used. It is not initialized or safe to use at boot when constructors normally are called. For this reason, when a class needs to be instantiated in external RAM somehow the constructor needs to be prevented from running until external RAM is ready for use. What is the best way of doing this?

One option I can think of is to allocate some space for the object that has the correct size and alignment and later call placement new on this location.

```
static ALTRAM union 
{
    UINT64 alignment;
    UINT8 space[sizeof(ClassName)]
}spaceHolder;
ClassName* classInstance = NULL;
...
classInstance new (&spaceHolder) ClassName();
```

Another option that was suggested is to instantiate the object as a static function object in a function that passes a pointer to the instance. My concern here is that it seems the standard allows the constructor to be called on the first call to the function but it doesn't seem that all compilers are required to do this.
[See bold text from the standard](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/08/30/construction-of-function-static-variables-in-c-is-not-thread-safe).

```
static ClassName& GetInstance()
{
    static ALTRAM ClassName instance;
    return instance;
}
```

The project compiles for Win32 VC++ and Keil for ARM but only has this requirement for the ARM. Are there pragmas or any other method to prevent constructors from being called?

I am looking for solutions that do not require the class to be modified.

**Update**

Thank you everyone for your replies it has been very helpful. I have come to the following conclusions:

1. The architecture should initialize the hardware before the application runs. This problem has sparked a lot of discussion on our team and it will most likely be fixed.
2. A few people prefer the placement new approach.
3. For the other approach the C++ standard requires that the the constructor is called the first time the function executes so this should be a reliable and portable solution.

Comment: What's wrong with the placement new method?

Comment: Shouldn't it be the job of the operating system to not apply the use of this memory until it is ready? Shouldn't you solve this at the OS level rather than the application level?

Comment: @JesperJuhl  Yes, the OS level solution is being investigated but nothing yet.

Comment: You need another program do initialize the hardware first before this one can use it, just like some SoCs needs 3 stages of boot loaders to boot into linux.

Comment: @colojaro what does the program run on exactly? *Is* there an OS?

Comment: The usual architecture is to have at least two independent applications:  Bootloader and application.  The Bootloader initializes all hardware items and the platform (including memory access).  When it finishes, it jumps to the Application which contains the Run-Time-Library and initializes static variables.

Comment: The Keil compiler should come with some "startup" example code that performs initialization before the C++ environment is initialized.  Usually, this code sets up the ARM stack registers and other items.  You should place your memory initialization code in this "startup" code.

Comment: The bold text is not from the standard. A constructor of a function-scope static object will be called the first time the function is called, and no earlier.

Answer (score 0):

As has been suggested, set aside a block of memory and use placement new:

```
char object[sizeof(ClassName)];
new (&object) ClassName();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned about compilers being allowed to construct static local object earlier than needed, you can always add a level of indirection:

```
ClassName &getInstance() {
    static ClassName *instance(NULL);
    if(!instance) instance = new ClassName;
    return *instance;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this statically allocated in external RAM and not on the heap?

Comment: Most likely. For example, you could use placement `new` and add a static boolean flag pre-set to true: `static ClassName *instance(ADDRESS); static bool undefined(true); if(undefined) { new(instance) ClassName; undefined = false; }`.

Answer (score 0):

Many compilers that support embedded systems come with some "startup" example code that performs initialization before the C++ environment is initialized. Usually, this code sets up the ARM stack registers and other items. The code is probably in assembly language.  You should place your memory initialization code in this "startup" code.